# Connected sum of 2 annuli (reading John. M. Lee's Introduction to topological manifolds)

Tags: general-topology, geometric-topology

I am a beginner in topology and have been reading John M.Lee's Introduction to Topological Manifolds for the past 2 weeks. My question is concerned with the concept of connected sums, and in turn have other related questions. I have probably used incorrect terms unknowingly; please correct me.

My aim: To obtain the connected sum of 2 annuli in $\mathbb{R}^2$. I need a big picture understanding of the concept, and want to clarify if I'm on the right path, before ironing out the details.

What I've done: I'm able to define the topology of 1 annulus using open sets, by using the exponential quotient map. Chapter 6 of the book, under Connected Sums of Surfaces mentions that one needs to use a connected surface for the connected sum. So, I verify on pg. 90 of the book, under example 4.16(c) that $\mathbb{R}^2\setminus {0}$ is path-connected, and thus is connected. Since the annulus is homeomorphic or topologically equivalent to $\mathbb{R}^2\setminus {0}$, the annulus is also path-connected, and thus is connected. Thus, it is a valid candidate to be used for the connected sum operation.

Where I'm getting stuck: I'm having trouble defining the second annulus. I could define the second annulus in a manner similar to the first, and with a shifted origin. But, if that is so, it means that the annulus is located on the same space. Then that means that I am puncturing the already origin-punctured plane, yet again. Am I thinking correctly so far? If so, this topological space is not connected anymore; right? If not, how would I reason it? The confusion is that the annuli need to be a disjoint union of topological spaces, but I don't know how to treat them separately. They look like 2 annuli in the same space in my mind, so I'm confused about how each of their relationships to the punctured plane looks like. I think they should look like a disjoint union of annuli and equivalently a disjoint union of punctured planes; but because the punctured plane goes to infinity in both directions, I am now terribly confused.

What I think I should do: Define the second annulus the same way as the first using the exponential quotient map and the homeomorphism to $\mathbb{R}^2\setminus {0}$. Then, as part of the connected sum operation, remove an open coordinate ball (in this case a disc) from each annulus. It leaves behind a boundary homeomorphic to $\mathbb{S}^1$ in each. Then, when defining the equivalence class to connect the 2 annuli along that left-behind boundary, use:

1. A translation to map the two left-over boundaries to overlap. Translation is invariant under homeomorphism, so this should be fine.
2. How do I move the rest of the second annulus? The equivalence class applies only to the left-over boundary after the ball removal. So, can I define another map to map the remaining part of the annulus?
3. Once we have the quotient map, we verify that they do locally resemble a homeomorphic space, and if necessary, to preserve orientation, a composition of homeomorphisms can be used to achieve the desired adjunction space. Right?

Topology is not my background, so please excuse the crduity of my understanding/the thought process. I want to understand it systematically. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a pointer in the correct direction. If you take the plane, and remove three distinct points, then the result is homeomorphic to the connect sum of a pair of annuli.

Comment: The 2 distinct points make sense; but I'm dicey on the third one. Is it because of the definition of the quotient map and the quotient space itself? That is, the resulting quotient space $X \Cup_f Y$ is a disjoint union of $q(X)$ and $q(Y \setminus A)$ (since one is closed and the other is open)?  If that is the reason, then how does the connected sum at the point of connection achieve local homeomorphism with the Euclidean space?

Comment: When you form a connect sum of surfaces the new surface has “punctures” in bijection with the disjoint union of the “punctures” of the original surfaces.

Comment: You are clearly very confused by the notion of quotients.  That is not a bad thing - they are one of the most difficult topics in a first course,  I suggest that you do a few easier exercises, and the return to this question.

Comment: For example: what spaces can you get from a pair of closed intervals (copies of the closed unit interval) by gluing their endpoints in different ways?

Comment: I certainly am confused. Ok will think about it and asnwer@ closed intervals. I am self-learning the concepts, so any pointer is great.  Also, what specifically should I focus on to gain a better understanding of quotients? And yes, I will need to come back to this question.

Comment: Three suggestions: Focus on understanding quotients before understanding connect sums. And draw some pictures. And find a study partner, if you can. (Faster feedback is better feedback.)

Answer (score -1):

Disclaimer: I'm not sure about your definition of an annulus, so I assume you mean $S^1$. If you reject the temptation of puting everything down in coordinates, things might become clearer. I just read the definition of a connected sum, and it seems to me that the connected sum of two annuli would be another annuli, no? I imagined two rings and I cut out a small segment from each of them. Next I glue the two pairs of exposed points. Then I get another ring, which is an annulus in your words.

Comment: An annulus is a two-dimensional surface, not a one-dimensional curve. There are two common definitions: an annulus is the Cartesian product of the circle with the closed, or open, interval.  The original post is asking about the latter definition.  It is an exercise to show that the once punctured plane, the twice punctured sphere, and the open annulus are all homeomorphic.

Comment: The connect sum of two surfaces, say $S$ and $T$, is defined by removing a small open disk from each and gluing (via homeomorphism) the resulting new boundary components.